# Implementing the useDelimiter method

Tags: java

I have the following code, please keep in mind I'm just starting to learn a language and a such have been looking for fairly simple exercises. Coding etiquette and critics welcome.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Tron
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int x,z,y = 0;
        File Tron= new File("C:\\Java\\wordtest.txt");
        Scanner word = new Scanner(Tron);
        HashMap<String, Integer> Collection = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        //noticed that hasNextLine and hasNext both work.....why one over the other?
        while (word.hasNext())
        {
            String s = word.next();
            Collection.get(s);
            if (Collection.containsKey(s))
            {
                Integer n = Collection.get(s);
                n = n+1;
                Collection.put(s,n);
                //why does n++ and n+1 give you different results
            }else
            {
                Collection.put(s,1);
            }       
        }
        System.out.println(Collection);


    }   
}
```

Without the use of `useDelimiter()` I get my desired output based on the file I have:

```
Far = 2, ran = 4, Frog = 2, Far = 7, fast = 1, etc...
```

Inserting the `useDelimiter` method as follows

```
Scanner word = new Scanner(Bible);
word.useDelimiter("\\p{Punct} \\p{Space}");
```

provides the following output as it appears in the text file shown below.

> the the the the the
>
> frog frog
>
> ran
>
> ran ran ran
>
> fast, fast fast
>
> far, far, far far far far far

Why such a difference in output if `useDelimiter` was supposed to account for punctuation new lines etc? Probably pretty simple but again first shot at a program. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Please post the input (the actual contents of *wordtest.txt*) too.

Answer (score 2):

With `word.useDelimiter("\\p{Punct} \\p{Space}")` you are actually telling the scanner to look for delimiters consisting of a punctuation character *followed by* a space *followed by* another whitespace character. You probably wanted to have *one (and only one) of these* instead, which would be achieved by something like

```
word.useDelimiter("\\p{Punct}|\\p{Space}");
```

or *at least one* of these, which would look like

```
word.useDelimiter("[\\p{Punct}\\p{Space}]+");
```

#### Update

@Andrzej nicely answered the questions in your code comments (which I forgot about), however he missed one little detail which I would like to expand / put straight here.

> why does n++ and n+1 give you different results

This obviously relates to the line

```
            n = n+1;
```

and my hunch is that the alternative you tried was

```
            n = n++;
```

which indeed gives confusing results (namely the end result is that `n` is *not* incremented).

The reason is that `n++` (the *postfix increment operator* by its canonical name) increments the value of `n` but *the result of the expression is the original value of `n`!* So the correct way to use it is simply

```
            n++;
```

the result of which is equivalent to `n = n+1`.

Here is [a thread with code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators-need-help-with-example) which hopefully helps you understand better how these operators work.

Answer (score 0):

Péter is right about the regex, you're matching a very specific sequence rather than a class of characters.

I can answer the questions from your source comments:

> noticed that hasNextLine and hasNext both work.....why one over the other?

The `Scanner` class is declared to implement `Iterator<String>` (so that it can be used in any situation where you want some arbitrary thing that provides Strings).  As such, since the `Iterator` interface declares a `hasNext` method, the Scanner needs to implement this with the exact same signature.  On the other hand, `hasNextLine` is a method that the Scanner implements on its own volition.

It's not entirely unusual for a class which implements an interface to declare both a "generically-named" interface method and a more domain-specific method, which both do the same thing.  (For example, you might want to implement a game-playing client as an `Iterator<GameCommand>` - in which case you'd *have* to declare `hasNext`, but might want to have a method called `isGameUnfinished` which did *exactly* the same thing.)

That said, the two methods aren't identical.  `hasNext` returns true if the scanner has another *token* to return, whereas `hasNextLine` returns true if the scanner has another *line of input* to return.

I expect that if you run the scanner over a file which doesn't end in a newline, and consume all but one of the tokens, then `hasNext` would return `true` while `hasNextLine` would return false.  (If the file ends in a newline then both methods will *behave* the same - as there are more tokens if and only if not all lines have been consumed - but they're not *technically* the same.)

> why does n++ and n+1 give you different results

This is quite straightforward.

`n + 1` simply returns a value that is one greater than the current value of `n`.  Whereas `n++` **sets n to be one greater**, and then returns that value.

So if `n` was currently 4, then both options would *return* 5; the difference is that the value of `n` would still be 4 if you called `n + 1` but it would be 5 if you called `n++`.

In general, it's wise to avoid using the `++` operator except in situations where it's used as boilerplate (such as in `for` loops over an index).  Taking two or three extra characters, or even an extra line, to express your intent more clearly and unambiguously is such a small price that it's almost always worth doing.

Comment: *"n++ sets `n` to be one greater, and then returns that value"* - no, its result is the *original* value of `n`. OTOH `++n` does what you describe.