# Decrement in Java

Tags: java

```
int result = 5;    
result = result--;  
System.out.println(result);
```

Why is the result equal to 5?

Comment: Maybe see here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100211211451AACctJj

Comment: And read [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/411365/java/java/Post-increment-Pre-Increment-Precedence) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/explain-working-of-post-and-pre-increment-operator-in-java)

Comment: lol you guys are jumping this question like savages ^^

Comment: java is like any other language. You could express very silly things like `x = x --`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This does nothing :

```
   result = result--;
```

Because `result--` returns the value of result before it is decremented (contrary to `--result` which returns the value of result after it is decremented).
And as the part to the right of `=` is executed before the `=`, you basically decrement result and then, on the same line, set result to the value it had before the decrement, thus canceling it in practice.

So you could write

```
   result = --result;
```

But if you want to decrement result, simply do

```
result--;
```

(or `--result;` but it's very unusual and atypical to use it on its own, don't do it when you don't want to use the result of the expression but simply want to decrement)

Comment: "this is very unusual and atypical, don't do it" - this is pure gold :)

Comment: @maksimov : I'm not a native english speaker so maybe I miss something, can you explain ?

Comment: What's wrong with prefix decrement? :)

Comment: @jsalonen its unusual and atypical, which it is to fair

Comment: I was referring to using it on his own, not in an expression using it.

Comment: @dystroy your English is fine, it's just the statement sounds as if we are dealing with something superficial here and we don't really know what to expect :)

Comment: A few days before I was told on SO that I was making hard to read code by writing `for(var i=a.length;i-->0;)` ...

Comment: It is indeed quite hard to read

Comment: I can understand this as a "this is just how it works" but I'd really like to understand it in more depth. Could someone explain this in more detail? From my current understanding, even though `result = result--;` is weird, it should still _work_ For example `result--;` will decrement result and the value of result will actually change. So if you do `result = result--;` wouldn't the logic work like this? `result = result;` is what it sees first. Then, wouldn't it perform the `result--;`? Why doesn't it?

Comment: this line gives to result the value of `result--`. `result--` does 2 things : it decrements AND it returns a value (the one before the decrement). So that just after having decremented (what's on the right of the `=` is executed first), you set the value of result to the one before the decrement. So you do a decrement and then cancel it.

Answer (score 15):

Because the value of the expression `result--` is the value of `result` *before* the decrement. Then `result` is decremented and finally the value of the expression is assigned to `result` (overwriting the decrement).

Answer (score 5):

Very valid question!

Your code doesn't work since `result--` is performed only after the substitution `=`. Your code would work had you used prefix operator:

```
result = --result;
```

However that doesn't make any sense as you can simply write:

```
--result;
```

For a more thorough explanation see [this question/answers on how prefix/postfix operators work on Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators-need-help-with-example).

Answer (score 4):

This is confusing construct. Its the same as

```
int tmp = result;
result--;  
result = tmp;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the post-decrement operator. This is because you are writing `result--` but not `--result`. The value of the expression `result--` is a copy of `result`, it is defined *before* the decrementing. That's why it's called *post*-decrement.

After the value of the expression `result--` is defined, `result` is decremented. **But:** Right after this, the value of `result` is overriden by the value of the `result--` expression (`result = 5`), which was 5.

Answer (score 2):

result-- is post decrement.. which means that the value is first assigned to result and then decremented.

you  might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java) helpful.

I believe what you want to do is :

```
int result = 5;     
result--; 
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

change to prefix increment to get desired result, or remove the assignment statement:

```
int result = 5;
result = --result;
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

result=--result;
it will print 4, and you will come to the understanding of what is the diffrence between 
c-- and --c