# Post Decrement in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decrement in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086765/decrement-in-java)

I was looking at this question, [Decrement in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086765/decrement-in-java#11086765) and it piqued my curiosity. I understand how post/pre increment/decrement work, but I want to know why it works the way it does in that particular situation.

For example,

```
int x = 5;
x--;
```

Will very obviously set x to be 4. But if you do,

```
x = x--;
```

x will be 5 still (as discovered by the poster of the referenced question). From my understanding of post decrement, it returns the value before it modifies it. So what I expect to happen would be that `x = 5` happens first. (keeping consistent with the above). Then, x is decremented, so in my mind, `x--;` would run, which in the above clearly sets x to be 4.

I mean, yes, it's easy enough just to do `x--;` but I would like to understand why Java's post decrement works this way.

I tried the code below and it worked exactly as expected.

```
int x = 5;
int y = x--;
```

`y` was set to 5 and `x` was properly decremented. Why doesn't the same happen for `x = x--;`?

Comment: As explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11086829/829571).

Comment: This is similar to, but asking more detail from that question.

Comment: @assylias That is actually exactly what I was looking for! I can't believe I didn't look at that answer. I think I'm too used to looking at the top answers. I thought that `x = x--;` would rather be `int tmp = x; x = tmp; x--;` I had the order switched.