# Whats does this do in java? I don't understand --variable

Tags: java

```
array[i] = array[--size];
```

I understand that variable-- is equal to variable - 1 but what is --variable equal to and does it do something special when it is in the array brackets?  I guess this removes something from the array I really don't understand the code here.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Comment: Related: [Java: Prefix/postfix of increment/decrement operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548)

Comment: `--variable` is similar, except it evaluates to the value *after* decrementing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i-- and --i do essentially the same thing: They subtract 1 from i. The difference is that i-- will subtract 1 after an action is completed, while --i will subtract one before the action. This makes more sense in the case of a for loop:

```
for (i = 5; i > 0; i--) {...}
```

In this case, the for loop will run with i equaling 5, then at the end of the loop, it will repeat, but subtract 1.
If the case was this:

```
for (i = 5; i > 0; --i) {...}
```

i would have 1 subtracted from it BEFORE the loop runs, so it would start off immediately with 0, but on the other hand, it would also run at the end when i = 0.

Saying `--size` is like saying the value of `size` minus 1.

Comment: Do either of them save the new value of the variable though or is it just a temporary thing?

Comment: This opening explanation is correct but the for-loop example is incorrect: {...} will run with i = 5 first before being decremented by either '--i' or 'i--', which will amount to the same in this example.

Answer (score 3):

The code sets `size = size - 1` and afterwards copies the element at `size` to `i`.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply equivalent to:

```
size-=1;
array[i] = array[size];
```

Comment: No, it's not. It's the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is identical to:

```
size--;
array[i] = array[size];
```

Prefix decrement is very similar to postfix, the only difference being that it evaluates to the result *after* the decrement, rather than the value *before*.

Answer (score 1):

The variable size was defined earlier in your code.  The -- infront of the variable name causes to to decrease by 1 prior to executing that line of code.  For example if the size variable was set to 5, prior to the assignment occurring the size variable would decrease to 4 and then perform the assignment of array[i] = array[4].

Answer (score 1):

It's simply does this :

```
size-=1;
array[i] = array[size];
```

`--variable` indicates pre decrement. That is first the value will be decremented and then used.

Answer (score 1):

`--` substracts one from the variable, but the position of the `--` (or `++`) controls when the variable is decremented

- `array[--size]` subtracts one before the array is accessed
- `array[size--]` would subtract one after the array has been accessed

Answer (score 0):

The `array[index]` returns the element in the `array` at the `index` location.

The `--value` means evaluate the value as `value = value - 1` and then apply the new value in the operation.