# I don't know why my variables are getting these values

Tags: java

```
public int Gauss_Jordan(double[][] matrix, int numOfRows, int numOfCols) {
    for (int col_j = 0; col_j<numOfCols; col_j++) {
        row_i = nonzeros ++;
        System.out.println(row_i+" and "+nonzeros);
    }
    //return matrix;

    return 0;
}
```

up above in the method called "Gauss_Jordan", you can see a for loop where it iterates until a certain condition is met. (duh.. lol sorry).

so i set row_i = nonzeros++ but here's the thing, when I print out each iteration i get

- 0 and 1,
- 1 and 2,
- 2 and 3

. I would expect the output to be:

- 1 and 1,
- 2 and 2,
- 3 and 3.

How come this is not the case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators-need-help-with-example

Comment: What is nonzeros? I don't see it initialized?

Answer (score 4):

You'd need `++nonzeros` instead of `nonzeros++` to get what you expect.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ... Pretty sure he was ..... what's the issue?

Comment: time to drink more coffee. that's the issue. sorry.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels go back to the java tutorial .... ;-) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Comment: @rolfl: my eyes weren't seeing things clearly. 1+ to bruno and sanbhat.

Comment: +1 from me on the coffee ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Thats called post-increment;

When you say `row_i = nonzeros ++;`

first the `row_i` will get assigned with the value of `nonzeros` and the `nonzero` will get incremented.

try pre-increment

```
row_i = ++nonzeros;
```

Answer (score 0):

If pre-increment is not what you wanted. Check the initialization of `nonzeros` and change it into '1` for it to show up as you want. Your codes are functioning as they should.