# Constructors calling in Java

Tags: java, static

In here:

[image]

The output should be 9, Why is 10?

Can anybody explain me step by step?

Comment: why should be 9?

Comment: Note: this has *nothing* to do with constructors.

Comment: @user2864740 in some ways it does. The constructor call with ++ is involved. And he just doesn't know what to ask.

Comment: @Zaphod42 This could be written to reproduce the same behavior using normal methods (the `super()` can be dropped and the `this()` can be converted into a method call).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `while` loop exits when `count` is 10 (9 is still less than 10).

Then you `println` `count`, whose value is 10.

Finally you increment its value which, after printing, it's 11.

Comment: This is incorrect, the value of count is 9, but then count is called with ++ before being passed to Pangool() constructor.

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
Pangool(){
    while(count < 10)
        new Pangool(++count)
}
```

Will increment `count` from 0 all the way to 10.

Then at here:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    new Pangool();
    new Pangool("Pangool");
    System.out.println(count++);
}
```

It will print the current value of `count`, **then** increment `count`.  This line:

```
System.out.println(count++);
```

is equivalent to:

```
System.out.println(count);
count = count + 1;
```

[If you write out the code and add a few print statements, you can see the flow of the value](http://ideone.com/Fon87J):

```
before:  0
after:  1
before:  1
after:  2
before:  2
after:  3
before:  3
after:  4
before:  4
after:  5
before:  5
after:  6
before:  6
after:  7
before:  7
after:  8
before:  8
after:  9
before:  9
after:  10
10
10
11
```

Answer (score 2):

**Lemme walk you through it:**

First it calls `new Pangool()` which starts the loop

**count is initialized to 0**

we now call `Pangool(++count)`, which increases count to 1 and passes the value of 1 (count++ would have passed 0 and changed it to 1 afterwards). **Count is 1.**

this calls the `Pangool(int)` constructor which does nothing

the loop continues with the value increasing, up to where **count is 9**, on this loop we now call `Pangool(++count)` which increases **count to 10**.

Now we're done with `Pangool()` and count is 10

Now we call `Pangool("Pangool")` which invokes the string constructor which does nothing to count, still 10.

Now we call `System.out.println(count++)`, this **prints count at 10, then changes count to 11**.

`System.out.println(count)` would print 11 after.

check out pre-fix and post-fix operators here:

[Java: Prefix/postfix of increment/decrement operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you start the count at 0 and stop at 9, 9 included.
Your count start at 0 and increments by 1 for about 10 times.
If you count number by number, 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, you can see that there are 10 numbers.