# It won't check if arrays are in ascending order

Tags: arrays, sorting

```
   int [] ary1 = new int [100];
   int [] ary2 = new int [100];


   System.out.println("Enter no more than 100 integers in ascending order. To end, enter a negative number.");
   int num1 = user.nextInt();
   int count1 = 0;
   while ((num1 > -1) && (count1 < ary1.length)){
   ary1[count1] = num1;
   count1++;
   num1 = user.nextInt();
```

this is the first array.

users can enter no more than 100 integers, will stop if user entered a negative number.

```
    if (num1 < 0){ 
    System.out.println("Enter your second list of integers from least to greatest. To end, enter a negative number.");
    int num2 = user.nextInt();
    int count2 = 0;
    while ((num2 > -1) && (count2 < ary2.length)){
    ary2[count2] = num2;
    count2++;
    num2 = user.nextInt();
```

this is the second array.

users can enter no more than 100 integers, will end if user entered a negative number.

```
    if (num2 < 0){
      for (int one = 0; one < count1; one++){
        System.out.print(ary1[one]+" ");}
```

print out the first list of integers

```
      System.out.println("");     **//skip a line**

      for (int two =0; two < count2; two++){
        System.out.print(ary2[two]+" ");}   p
```

rint out the second list of integers

```
      System.out.println("");     **//skip a line**
```

**the problem is here, it won't check if the arrays are in ascending order. ↓↓↓**

```
       int inOrder = 0;    
      for (int check1 = 0; check1 < count1-1; check1++){
        if (ary1[check1] > ary1[check1++]){
          System.out.println("Error: Array not in correct order.");
          break;
        }else{
           inOrder = 1;
        }}

        for (int check2 = 0; check2 < count2-1; check2++){
        if (ary2[check2] > ary2[check2++]){
          System.out.println("Error: Array not in correct order.");
          break;
        }else{
          inOrder = 1;
        }} 



        }}
    }  }}}
```

if inOder = 1, i will need to merge the 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with how you are incrementing your check1 and check2 variables:

```
if (ary1[check1] > ary1[check1++]){ }
if (ary2[check2] > ary2[check2++]){ }
```

For these loops, you are using `check1++` and `check2++`.  Putting `++` at the end of a variable name evaluates to the expression value prior to the increment.  Putting `++` BEFORE the variable name increments the variable first and then evaluates the expression.  The fix is to just relocate your `++` like this:

```
if (ary1[check1] > ary1[++check1]){ }
if (ary2[check2] > ary2[++check2]){ }
```

Look at this post to understand prefix/postfix operators better:

[Java: Prefix/postfix of increment/decrement operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators)

**Update:**  Other user noticed that the increment is actually happening twice due to loop control also doing ++.  To fix, replace `++check1` with `check + 1`.  I almost feel guilty having this accepted as correct!

Comment: this would only check a pair each time as check1 or check2 is being incremented by 2 each loop

Comment: Example 0,2,1,3 = first loop compares 0 and 2 which is valid, and then compares 1 and 3 which is also correct. It skips checking 2 and 1 so would not give correct result

Comment: Good catch @Geezer68 -- did not look too closely at external loop code

Comment: I'd help them with the inOrder check as well - should initially be set to a true value and only set to false before the break statement:)

Answer (score 0):

The ++ is the problem:

```
if (ary1[check1] > ary1[check1++])
```

Change this to:

```
if (ary1[check1] > ary1[check1 + 1])
```