# Why do "--i" and "i--" have the same behavior in a Java for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

Why is it that in Java, **i--** and **--i** have the same behavior inside a *for loop* ?

ex.:
My variable "i" doesn't decrease before looping:

```
for(int i = 5; i > 0; --i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

and

```
for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

... will both print 5,4,3,2,1.

But this:

```
int i = 5;
System.out.println(--i);


int i = 5;
System.out.println(i--);
```

...will print 4 and 5.

Comment: See this question on the difference between the pre and post decrement operators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators

Comment: "Why --i doesn't work in java for loop?" - It works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For loops work like this:

```
for(<Part that will be executed before the loop>;
    <Part that is the condition of the loop>;
    <Part that will be executed at the end of each iteration) {
    <statements>
}
```

Any for loop can thus be rewritten like so:

```
<Part that will be executed before the loop>
while(<Part that is the condition of the loop>) {
    <statements>
    <Part that will be executed at the end of each iteration>
}
```

Using your example to do that results in:

```
int i = 5; // Part that will be executed before the loop
while(i > 0) { // Part that is the condition of the loop
    System.out.println(i); // statements
    --i; // Part that will be executed at the end of each iteration
}
```

As you can see it doesn't matter for the output if it's `--i` or `i--` since the print call will always happen before the variable is decremented. To achieve your desired result you can try this:

```
int i = 5;
while(i > 0) {
    --i;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mhlz! Can we state then that "for(int i = 5; i > 0; --i)" is exactly the same as "for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--)" ?

Comment: Both will produce exactly the same result, so I guess you could say that.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `for` loop works like this:

```
for (<1. variable declaration and initialization>;
     <2. condition to loop>;
     <4. for update>) {
    <3. statements>
}
```

Your `i--` or `--i` condition is executed after the execution of the statements in the `for` loop and before checking the condition to loop. Which means, it doesn't matter if you use `i--` or `--i` in the *for update* section.

Answer (score 4):

Both `--i` and `i--` have the same side effect, decrementing `i` by one. They differ in their result value. In the loop code you are only using the side effect, ignoring the result. In the freestanding `println` code you are displaying the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to put it is that, in the loops, you are printing like this:

```
System.out.println(i);
```

Notice the argument to println() is "i", not "i--" or "--i". The decrement has already taken place elsewhere. You are not printing the result of the decrement but the value of "i" within the loop.