# Difference between prefix and postfix ++ operators in Java

Tags: java, jvm, operators, bytecode

There are a few questions regarding this (like [Java: Prefix/postfix of increment/decrement operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators)) but I'm **not** asking about the general difference between postfix and prefix `++` operators (I know that part), but about the **fundamental difference between them at the Java specification level**.

Specifically, is there any difference between prefix and postfix `++` operators *other* than operator precedence (maybe in the way the javac translates the commands to bytecode or in the way the JVM runs that bytecode)?

For example, would the following code **necessarily** run the same (in every JVM):

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) { ... }
```

And

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i) { ... }
```

Is there anything in the JLS that defines that these 2 statements would run in exactly the same way on every platform, Java compiler, JVM, etc., or is it possible (even theoretically) that these 2 statements will run differently?

Comment: just only add before and add after different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant parts of the specification are:

> #### [15.15.1. Prefix Increment Operator ++](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1)
>
> […]
>
> At run time, if evaluation of the operand expression completes abruptly, then the prefix increment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no incrementation occurs. Otherwise, the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable. […]
> The value of the prefix increment expression is the value of the variable *after* the new value is stored.

> #### [15.14.2. Postfix Increment Operator ++](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)
>
> […]
>
> At run time, if evaluation of the operand expression completes abruptly, then the postfix increment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no incrementation occurs. Otherwise, the value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into the variable. […]
> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable *before* the new value is stored.

So, the *only* difference is the result value when used in an expression context. When using it in the context of a `for` loop’s update clause, there relevant part is:

> #### [14.14.1.2. Iteration of for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.2)
>
> […]
>
> [→](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.2-100-B-A-A) First, if the *ForUpdate* part is present, the expressions are evaluated in sequence from left to right; their values, if any, are discarded. If evaluation of any expression completes abruptly for some reason, the for statement completes abruptly for the same reason; any *ForUpdate* statement expressions to the right of the one that completed abruptly are not evaluated.

Taking it *literally* there would be a difference in the code as these expressions produce different results which are then discarded. However, this difference lies in non-observable behavior and as a consequence, the code is usually compiled to not produce the value in the first place and hence does not differ.

So the answer is, the code *may* have differences, e.g. when compiled naively, however the observable behavior is guaranteed to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it would run the same. It would compile to the same bytecode, thus JVM will notice no difference whatever JVM it is.

You may check it by yourself:

```
public class TestIncrement {
    public void testPost(int X) {
        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public void testPre(int X) {
        for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Both methods are compiled in the same way using either JavaC compiler:

```
public void testPost(int);
Code:
   0: iconst_0
   1: istore_2
   2: iload_2
   3: iload_1
   4: if_icmpge     20
   7: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  10: iload_2
  11: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
  14: iinc          2, 1
  17: goto          2
  20: return
```

Or ECJ compiler:

```
public void testPost(int);
Code:
  0: iconst_0
  1: istore_2
  2: goto          15
  5: getstatic     #16                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  8: iload_2
  9: invokevirtual #22                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
 12: iinc          2, 1
 15: iload_2
 16: iload_1
 17: if_icmplt     5
 20: return
```

Different compilers generate different bytecode, but in both cases the bytecode is the same for both methods.

Comment: Can you provide some reference...?

Comment: Added bytecode generated by two Java compilers. In both cases there's no difference.

Comment: That's nice, but you just showed that 2 compilers provide the same output - I asked if it will *necessarily* run the same. Could there be another Java compiler that will produce different outputs?

Comment: The observed behavior must be the same: see @Kayaman answer. The performance *theoretically* might be different, but I don't see any reasons for this. Of course you may create your own JLS-compliant bytecode compiler (or fork existing one) which will add several useless instructions for postincrement, just to prove that's the difference is possible.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. My question is theoretical by nature.

Comment: I don't understand why people keep upvoting this answer. It should be clear to anyone who reads the question carefully enough that this does **not** answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main points of Java is that the code will run the same on every JVM. While compilers can generate different bytecode for the same source code, they need to follow a set of rules, just like the different JVMs, to ensure that things run correctly.

There is no undefined or platform dependent behaviour like in for example C.

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

> The *increment* expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment *or* decrement a value.

From [Oracle documentation on JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.2):

> First, if the *ForUpdate* part is present, the expressions are evaluated in sequence from left to right; their values, if any, are discarded.

As it is invoked *after* the iteration and the return values are discarded, it shouldn't be any difference between both options. Maybe the bytecode is not exactly the same, but it should be equivalent.

Comment: I will change the "probably" to "maybe", as we haven't check on _every_ compiler.

Comment: Upvoted. I think this is the most relevant answer so far (even though it looks like most people don't seem to realise that) but I'll wait to see if someone provides more elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

There are already good answers here, but I would like to try to answer it from another perspective. I will only look at how the `for` loop must work, in any language that has the same type of `for` loop that Java does.

It has four parts:

- An initialization part
- A conditional part
- A loop variable modification part
- A body part to loop through

Any compiler needs to handle them separately, they can't optimize by joining them in any way. *(According to me anyway.)* Each part must be looked at as an isolated entity of some kind. We are only interested in the *loop variable modification* part in this discussion.

Since it's an isolated entity, it can never matter if you use `i++` or `--i`. No Java compiler, any other compiler for other languages or any language parser can handle the `for` loop differently in that respect.

**That means the answer must be: Yes, they must run in the same way.**