# What happens when I increment the number I'm using to fetch an element from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I've been doing some algorithm questions and just saw a solution for a problem that is like this:

```java
public int longestOnes(int[] nums, int k) {
  int windowStart = 0, windowEnd;
  for (windowEnd = 0; windowEnd < nums.length; ++windowEnd) {
    if (nums[windowEnd] == 0) k--;
    if (k < 0 && nums[windowStart++] == 0) k++;
  }
  return windowEnd - windowStart;
}
```

Specifically in the part where **windowStart** is incremented (nums[windowStart++]), I understand that it will first fetch the value from **nums** array using the current **windowStart** value and then it will be incremented.

However, I don't understand exactly when this piece of code will be executed. Only when k < 0?

If so, is it correct to write this code like below:

```java
public int longestOnes(int[] nums, int k) {
  int windowStart = 0, windowEnd;
  for (windowEnd = 0; windowEnd < nums.length; ++windowEnd) {
    if (nums[windowEnd] == 0) k--;
    if (k < 0 && nums[windowStart] == 0) k++;
    if (k < 0) windowStart++;
  }
  return windowEnd - windowStart;
}
```

EDIT: I understand that in the third "if" k has been incremented and the condition is not gonna be the same. I'm just trying to wrap my head around it by writing that second "if" in a different way.

Somehow it seems to give me different results.

Would anyone know the difference and what exactly happens during that second condition (**if (k < 0 && nums[windowStart] == 0) k++;**)?

Comment: Nope, it's not correct to write the code as shown in the second snippet, because the value of `k` can change. `k` could be less than zero in the first `if`, and equal to zero in the second `if`.

Comment: I understand... That was a bad example. But how would you rewrite that nums[windowStart++] in a more legible way though still the same logic.

Comment: Your question is answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297641/difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators-in-java

Comment: @ChengThao Not exactly. I understand the increment operator. But I couldn't get the right order of that specific execution. Thanks though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rewrite produces different results because the second `if` you added is checking the *new* value of `k`, after it has been incremented in the previous line:

```
if (k < 0 && nums[windowStart] == 0) k++; // k is incremented here
if (k < 0) windowStart++; // then k is checked here
```

If `k` is `-1` and `nums[windowStart] == 0`. `k` will change to 0 in the first line, and the `k < 0` check in the second line will fail and `windowStart++` will not run.

In the original version, there is only one `k < 0` check, and `windowStart++` is run if that check is true.

If you want to rewrite the code in a way that doesn't put `windowStart++` inside the array index, you can do:

```
if (k < 0) {
    if(nums[windowStart] == 0) {
        k++;
    }
    windowStart++;
}
```

The idea is that `k < 0` is the condition on which we do `windowStart++`, but the old value of `windowStart` before we increment it is used to access the array. And we only increment `k` if both `k < 0` and `nums[windowStart] == 0` are true.

Comment: Thank you! That last code snipped you posted was precisely what I was missing.