# Java Increment / Decrement Operators - How they behave, what's the functionality?

Tags: java, oop, operators

It's been 3 days since I start to learn Java.
I have this program and I don't understand code in `main` method with `++` and `--` operators. I don't even know what to call them(name of these operators)
Can anyone explain me what's all about.

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         x=0;
         x++;
         System.out.println(x);
         y=1;
         y--;
         System.out.println(y);
         z=3;
         ++z;
         System.out.println(z);
     }
}
```

Comment: Code seems pretty simple. And integer declaration is `int x=0` and so on

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are called **Pre and Post Increment / Decrement Operators**.

```
x++;
```

is the same as `x = x + 1;`

```
x--;
```

is the same as `x = x - 1;`

Putting the operator before the variable `++x;` means, first increment `x` by 1, and then use this new value of `x`

```
int x = 0; 
int z = ++x; // produce x is 1, z is 1


    int x = 0;
    int z = x++;  // produce x is 1, but z is 0 , 
                  //z gets the value of x and then x is incremented.
```

Comment: Should add a line after your last line that prints out the value of z. Which shows that on the same line of post increment, the value does not change. However right afterwards int z takes on the new value, versus pre increment which is the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

`++` and `--` are called **increment** and **decrement** operators.
They are shortcuts for writing `x = x+1` (`x+=1`) / `x = x-1` (`x-=1`). (assumed that `x` is a numeric variable)

In rare cases you could worry about the precedence of the incrementation/decrementation and the value the expression returns: Writing `++x` it means "increment first, then return", whereas `x++` means "return first, then increment". Here we can distinguish between **pre-** and **post** increment/decrement operators.