# Checking for an an enum of the current enum

Tags: java, enums

In making a card game I came to a Straight, the numbers were set as an enum ace, two, three etc. and I wrote it like this

```
List<Number> number = Arrays.asList(Number.two, Number.two, Number.three, Number.four, Number.five);

private void Straight() {
    for(int currentCard = 0; currentCard < 4; currentCard++){
        for(int searchCard = 0; searchCard < 4; searchCard++){
        if (number.get(searchCard) == number.get(currentCard ++)){
            if (number.get(searchCard ++) == number.get(currentCard + 2)){
                if (number.get(searchCard + 2) == number.get(currentCard + 3)){

                }
            }
        }


        }
```

Looking at this I see currentCard will loop through the hand and not the enum set like I would like it to do. Which way would be most efficient to do this

Edit:
I tried writing up some code like this

```
Number currentCard = number.get(0);
```

but like I expected it was not equal to an integer value and now I am wondering if there is someway to put it equal to an integer.

Comment: Is that `java.lang.Number` you're using?

Comment: I am using an enum set that i named Number. @Paul

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. That's a really confusing name - I hope the name of the suit enum isn't `String`!  Seriously though, change the enum name to `Value` or make it part of the card class and reference it by `Card.Number` if you must.

Comment: Also, be careful with prefix and postfix increment operators, the statement `number.get(searchCard ++)` is not doing what you think it's doing. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30480534/4533771

Comment: You might want to take a look at the "ordinal" method of the `Enum` class. If you defined your enum as `ace`, `one`, `two`, `three`, etc. then `ace.ordinal()` will be 0, `one.ordinal()` will be 1. Of course, you'll have to write logic for ace being high and low.

Answer (score 0):

One of the primary things that make enums special is that they can be compared with == like primitive type.  Try looping through your enum tokens instead of ints.

```
List<Number> playerHand = Arrays.asList(Number.two, Number.two, Number.three, Number.four, Number.five);

public boolean isStraight(List<Number> hand) {
   int straightPosition = 0;
   boolean inStraightRun = false;
   Number lastStraightCard;
   for (int i = 0; i < Number.values().length; i++) {
       Number card = Number.values()[i];
       if (!inStraightRun) {
           if (card == hand[straightPosition]) {
               inStraightRun = true;
               lastStraightCard = card;
               straightPosition++;
           }
           else if (card == Number.ten) {
               break;//straight no longer possible
           }
       }
       else {
           if (card == hand[straightPosition] &&
               lastStraightCard == Number.values()[i - 1]) {
               lastStraightCard = card;
               straightPosition++;
           }
           else {
               break;//straight no longer possible
           }

           if (straightPosition > hand.length() - 1) {
               break;//straight! Stop looping
           }
       }
   }
   return straightPosition == hand.length();
}
```