# Java 'while loop' variable declared in parameter list

Tags: java, while-loop

What do I write inside the "while loop" parenthesis if the variable is declared inside the method parameter list? The goal is to print-out '+' in a row based on the given number of "x". For example, runLoop(3) will show "+++".

The solutions I have tried so far all result in an infinite loop.

Edit: thank you for all the answers!

```
public static void runLoop(int x){
     
    while(**???**){
        System.out.print("+");
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: that depends on your requirements, but it doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Exactly! We are just required to finish the while loop part of the code without removing the declared variable where it is now. The number of 'x' could be anything

Comment: If you want to loop a number of times equal to the value of the parameter, the number of loops is not unknown, and you should be looping until the loop counter is equal to the value of the parameter (inclusive or not, that depends on what you're doing inside the loop). Therefore, you probably don't want to increment the parameter, as you are doing, because that would cause an infinite loop if that parameter is also part of your loop termination condition.

Comment: as @JustAnotherDeveloper said, the number is not unknown, that is what made your question 'odd'. I'll give you a tip: you should not be incrementing x in that loop. What do you think you should do?

Comment: @Stultuske That's the thing, idk how to stop the loop once the condition has been met. I've tried while(true), while(x), and while(x==x) but all are infinite. I cant do while(x <= ??) or similar because theres no given range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:----

```
public static void runLoop(int x){
     
    while(x>0){
        System.out.print("+");
        x--;
    }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: It works! But can you please explain how? How does x-- function?

Comment: @MAnn see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30480534/11441011.

Comment: hey, Its called post decrement in java. its same as x=x-1( 1st assign the value n later decreases by 1)

Answer (score 1):

just loop while x greater than zero, you will need to change `x++` to `x--` inside the loop

```
while(x>0){
    System.out.print("+");
    x--;
}
```

Comment: It works! But can you please explain how? How does x-- function?

Comment: @MAnn `x--` is the same as `x = x - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

you can decrease the value of x just by one using a `post-decrement` and check whether its less greater then 0 or not if `true` then execute the body of while loop

```
public static void runLoop(int x){
    while(x-- > 0){
        System.out.print("+");
    }
}
```