# Control flow logic in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, control-flow

How is the following for loop different from original?
Why after initialization, it  checks for the condition?

Why such behavior and what are other such tricky behaviors of `for` loop?

```
class FooBar
{
static public void main(String... args)
{
    for (int x = 1; ++x < 10;)
    {
        System.out.println(x);  // it starts printing from 2

    }
}
}
```

**Output**:
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increment of `x` is combined with the condition.  Normally, the increment is performed in the third section of the `for` loop, which is a statement executed at the end of an iteration.

However, the condition is checked at the *beginning* of the loop.  It's an expression, not a statement, but as you can see, that doesn't stop someone from inserting a side-effect -- the pre-increment of `x`.

Because `x` starts out as `1`, the condition increments it to `2` before the first iteration.

Answer (score 3):

`++x` increments the value of `x`. As a result, two things are happening:

1. The value being checked for the for-loop condition (i.e., the inequality), is already incremented, and
2. This incremented value is what gets printed within the loop.

If you want values from 1 to 9, use the standard loop:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 10; ++x) { ... }
```

The effects of prefix and postfix operators has been discussed and explained in detail elsewhere, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators), for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is not for-loop trickery, it's the way the prefix and postfix operator works that you're using on `x`.

`++x` - Increment x then evaluate its value

`x++` - Evaluate the value of x and then increment it.

So, the loop with this definition:

```
for (int x = 1; ++x < 10;)
```

executes like this:

1. Initialize x to 1
2. Increment x by 1
3. Evaluate if x < 10.  If yes, iterate loop.  If no, end loop.

What you want is this:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
```

1. Initialize x to 1
2. Evaluate if x < 10.  If yes, iterate loop.  If no, end loop.
3. Increment x by 1

Comment: but doesnt it should have started printing from `1` like all for loops do and then go for condition check?

Answer (score 1):

Each `for-loop` (except enhanced for loop) has the following structure -

```
for(initialization; conditionChecking; increment/decrement){

   //body

}
```

Your `for-loop` also has this structure with the `incremetn/decrement` portion empty. But to continue the for loop you have to change index (here `x`) of `for-loop`. If it is done some how then you can leave the `increment/decrement` portion empty. If you write the `for-loop` like this then it also fine -

```
for(int x=0; x<10; ){
   //do something
   x++;
}
```

You also may leave one/more portion (even the body) of a `for-loop` empty, like this -

```
int x=0;
for(;x<10;x++); //empty body; do nothing; just increment x
```

Answer (score 1):

A for loop is valid with one or more of it's some portion leaving empty.
In the your code the increment portion is empty. You have done your increment of index `x` by using `++x>10`. So it is valid. There is no difference from the regular for loop, it's just a way of representing the for loop in different way.

Answer (score 1):

The Original way of a for loop  you may have in you mind:

`for(initialization; condition; inc/dec/divide..)`

And what you mentioned: `for (initialization; Inc & check; nothing)`

What does it mean? : `for(some blaBla; any Bla; some, more, bla)`

You may have any expression any where. The Original version is just a convention we follow. Go ahead an write a printing statement or a bitwise operator instead of `some blaBla` try it out!

**Update:**

Why :

```
  for (int x = 1; x++ < 10;)
      {
           System.out.println(x);

      }
```

Prints 2..10? For the answer first try to execute :

```
   for (int x = 1; ++x < 10;)
          {
               System.out.println(x);

          }
```

It prints from 2..9

You should understand how pre/post fix operators work. `x++` in the loop increments the value but not immediately. It increments after  `x++ < 10;`
Where as `++x < 10;` first increments and then rest everything happens.

So, when the x value is 9, 9(++)< 10 -> 9 is less ? yeah, now 9++ occurs.It then increments x. but ++x increments 1st so ++9< 10 -> 10<10 NO.

Comment: can you review Greg Hilston's answer and correct my queries that i have commented?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code as:

```
x = 1;
while (++x < 10)
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

You expect the following:

```
x = 1;
do
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
while (++x < 10);
```

This is the difference.

The following does what you expect:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Edit the comment.It starts printing from 1

Comment: Removed the comment. Was copy/paste from original posting.

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR* of it all is that `++x` is a pre increment operator. When you use `++x`, x will be incremented before any other allied operation. That is why your code prints out 2 first instead of 1 and stops when `++x` becomes 10