# java pre increment and post increment and self-assignment in loop

Tags: java

I expected post-increment and pre-increment of a variable and assignment of the result to itself to work a bit differently. But while the latter works as expected, the former runs as infinite while loop. Could someone please point out what i am missing here?

```
int y = 0;
int z = 4;

while(y<z)
{
    System.out.println(y);
    y =y++;//this prints 0 infinite times, shouldn't why be assigned values 0,1,2,3 with each pass?
    //y =++y;//this works as expected
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Just use `y++`.

Comment: What I think is happening is this: 1) a temporary value of `y` is stored somewhere, 2) `y` is incremented by one, then 3) `y` is assigned back to the temporary value.  Hence, the value of `y` never actually changes.  Anyway who has an exact duplicate feel free to hammer.

Answer (score 1):

As described in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413593/6685140), post increment works by storing a copy of y, adding 1 and returning the copy. This means that the return value of `y++` is not `y+1`, but still only `y`. Since you are overwriting `y` with `y++`, you are essentially just saying `y = y`.