# Operator Precedence in C++/Java

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I have been diving deep into understanding the operator precedence in Object oriented programming.
Given below is the code:

```
             int a=5;
             int b=5;
             printf("Output %d",a++>b);
             return 0;
```

The output is Output 0.

As per my understanding, unary operators has higher precedence over relational operator.
So shouldn't a++>b be 6>5. Which is True. But the code outputs False. can anybody explain me why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The postfix `a++` returns `5` - The prefix `++a` would return `6`

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031326/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-and-postfix-operators

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators

Comment: look similar to the ["goes to operator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c-c)

Comment: the value of `a++` is `5` not `6`

Comment: This isn't related to operator precedence at all because there's nothing to disambiguate. The only way to interpret this code is that `++` applies to `a` and `>` applies to `a++` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

You get `false` because you're using the postfix increment operator when you're doing `a++`, which in your case results in the comparison `5 > 5`.

The postfix increment operator can be thought of in this way. Note: It's illegal code made to demonstrate this only:

```
class int {                 // if there had been an "int" class
    int operator++(int) {   // postfix increment 
        int copy = *this;   // make a copy of the current value
        *this = *this + 1;  // add one to the int object
        return copy;        // return the OLD value
    }
};
```

If you had used the prefix increment operator, `++a`, you'd gotten the comparison `6 > 5` - and therefor the result `true`. The prefix increment operator can be thought of in this way. Again, illegal code:

```
class int {
    int& operator++() {    // prefix increment
        *this = *this + 1; // add one to the int object
        return *this;      // return a reference to the actual object
    }
};
```