# Foor loop doesn't work where condition is true

Tags: java, for-loop

I saw this code in a book.
The condition is true so why the result of this loop is 0?

```
boolean a = false;

for (int i = 0; a = !a ;) {

    System.out.println(i++);
}
```

Comment: Because `i++` behaves differently from `++i`: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i-in-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping until `a = !a` returns false, at which point the loop will break. This will happen on the second iteration (when `i` is equal to 1), as `a` will switch back to `false`.

**First iteration:**

`i` is equal to `0`, `a = !a` is evaluated which changes the value of `a` to true, hence the loop body executes. The value of `i` (zero) is printed and then incremented to 1 (this is a post-increment).

**Second iteration:**

`i` is equal to `1`, `a = !a` is evaluated which changes the value of `a` to false, hence the loop breaks.

Answer (score 2):

It works this way:

1. You execute `a = !a` it returns `true` you can test manually:

   ```
   System.out.println(a = !a);
   ```
2. Condition is true, so you execute loop body:

   ```
   System.out.println(i++);
   ```

`i++` is a [`postfix increment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators), so it first returns `i` value, which is `0`, after that increase it.

That's why the output of the program is `0`. If you try to print `i` after the loop, the output will be `1`.