# How do find if an index of int array ends on a specific digit Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a task to return an array of those numbers that end in `9`. Do not change the order of the remaining numbers.
The only thing I can use is a for loop.

My brain is kinda melted at the moment and I don't know what to do.

When I return a result, it returns as an `int` `3991599399`.

At the moment I think about how to take the result outside the for loop.
Сan you help me find a way to store all numbers with nines in a new array?

```java
    
public int[] leavePrice9(int[] prices) {
        
    for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            int result = prices[i];
            
            if (result % 10 == 9);
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QuadraticEquationSolver shop = new QuadraticEquationSolver();

        //Should be [399, 1599, 399]
        int[] prices = new int[] {399, 1599, 399, 50, 10, 10, 70};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shop.leavePrice9(prices)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your task. You want a method that takes an `int[]` and returns a new `int[]` of values that end in `9`; correct? What are "remaining numbers"? Also, can you use a collection like a `List` temporarily?

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I've changed the code to the correct one, the previous was in my draft, the only thing I can use is a for loop @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Right away, I see two problems with the code: 1) `leavePrice9(int[] prices)' is declared to return `int []`, but is missing a `return` statement.  2)   `if (result % 10 == 9);' doesn't do anything. `if (result % 10 == 9);' should have one statement before the `;` or be followed by a block, i.e., `{ ... }`, where `...` is one or more statements

Comment: AFAICT, the question is poorly worded. My interpretation is "Given an array of `int`, how can I return a subarray of only those elements that have a certain property?"

Comment: `IntStream.of(arr).filter(i -> i % 10 == 9).toArray()`

Comment: I understand your complaint @James, first I used code from my drafts here, it had System.out.print, then I changed to the moment when I got stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following method `getAllWithLastDigit()`. It takes an array of `int` and a digit (0-9) and returns a new array containing all elements that have that specified digit as the last digit. The elements of the original array remain untouched and therefore the order is obviously preserved.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] prices = new int[]{399, 1599, 399, 50, 10, 10, 70};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getAllWithLastDigit(prices, 9)));
    }

    public static int[] getAllWithLastDigit(int[] array, int lastDigit){
        if(lastDigit < 0 || lastDigit > 9) throw new IllegalArgumentException("lastDigit must be between 0 and 9!");
        var lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int result = array[i];
            if (result % 10 == lastDigit) lst.add(result);
        }
        // convert array list back to integer array
        return lst.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
    }
}
```

Expected ouput:

```
[399, 1599, 399]
```

This uses an `ArrayList` to be able to dynamically add elements to the list whenever we encounter an element that has 9 as the last digit. In the end we need to convert the list back to an array as you want to return an array of integers.

What you did is just string concatenation, instead of doing this we now add the element to a list, convert that list back to an `int` array and `return` it. Your implementation misses the part where a new array is created and returned.

### Edit

Here a version without using `ArrayList`. Here we first create an array capable of holding the maximum number of results and add a result to it while increasing a `counter` for each new element. Then we have to (possibly) shrink the array down so it only contains the number of elements that are actually within the array. For this we create a copy of the array with however many elements we have in our result.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] prices = new int[]{399, 1599, 399, 50, 10, 10, 70};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getAllWithLastDigit(prices, 9)));
    }

    public static int[] getAllWithLastDigit(int[] array, int lastDigit){
        if(lastDigit < 0 || lastDigit > 9) throw new IllegalArgumentException("lastDigit must be between 0 and 9!");
        // create an array which has the same size as the input, this way we guarantee that we have enough space for all result
        int[] elements = new int[array.length];
        // counter of how many elements are in the array 
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int result = array[i];
            if (result % 10 == lastDigit) elements[counter++] = array[i];
        }
        // now we need to create a new array which is exactly as long as we need it (if we don't have that already)
        if(counter == array.length) return elements;
        // Alternative: use Java API Arrays.copyOf(elements, counter)
        return copyArray(array, counter);
    }

    public static int[] copyArray(int[] array, int newLength){
        if(newLength < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length must not be < 0");
        var copy = new int[newLength];
        // make sure we don't go out of bounds because the new array could be longer than the old one
        var until = Math.min(array.length, newLength);
        // copy over all elements
        for (int i = 0; i < until; i++) {
            copy[i] = array[i];
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, unfortunately, we haven't passed the ArrayList on the courses yet.
I'll try to find a way to solve the task by using an additional loop.
And of course, I'll check the information regarding the ArrayList.
Thanks again :) @Mushroomator

Comment: You can do it with an `int` array as well. The problem is that you would need to know the size of the array beforehand which you don't or you would need to resize the array. Both can be done using an additional loop. This is just a more convenient way using some of the available Java APIs :)

Comment: I've now added a possible solution without `ArrayList`

Comment: I was doing something like this, but there is a mistake somewhere.
Your hint regarding Array size is helpful, thank you! @Mushroomator

Comment: public int[] leavePrice9(int[] prices) {
  
  int first = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
   int result = prices[i];
   if (result % 10 == 9) first++;
 }

  int result [] = new int[first];
  int index = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
   int price = prices[i];
   if (price % 10 == 9) result[index] = price;
 }
  return result;
}

@Mushroomator

Comment: You're not increasing `index` once you have inserted an element. Your `index` is always `0`, so it only ever modifies the first element in the array. Replace `result[index]` with `result[index++]` and it will work. Notice the [postfix notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators) - this is important here!.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version based on code of the O/P:

```
public int[] leavePrice9(int[] prices) {
    int count = 0;  // how many prices qualify? 
    int [] result = new int [prices.length]; // hold qualifying prices
    // worst case: every price will qualify.
    // result is large enough to handle worst case
        
    for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {                               
            if (prices[i] % 10 == 9)
                 result[count++] = prices [i];
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf (result, count);
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QuadraticEquationSolver shop = new QuadraticEquationSolver();

        //Should be [399, 1599, 399]
        int[] prices = new int[] {399, 1599, 399, 50, 10, 10, 70};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shop.leavePrice9(prices)));
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to be able to have **bold** withing `code`. I would like to be able to highlght the changes made to the O/P code.

Comment: Hello =) I made it with the next code, your's code looks much better than mine. Thank you! @James

Comment: public int[] leavePrice9(int[] prices) {
  
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
   int result = prices[i];
   if (result % 10 == 9) counter++;
 }

  int result [] = new int[counter];
  int newCounter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
   int price = prices[i];
   if (price % 10 == 9) result[newCounter++] = price;
 }
  return result;
} @James